# OpenCV Deployment

Tags: c++, qt, opencv

I am developing a Qt application using OpenCV. It works fine on my PC. Even when I create a "Release" Version and execute the .exe from Release folder it works fine on my pc.

But when I startup this .exe on another pc there is a problem: the part of application which doesn't use OpenCV (QT's widgets) is working fine, but when I click on the button which uses OpenCV, my application crashes with no Error.

Comment: I think the program does not find the .dll files from opencv. Maybe you need to copy some opencv .dll files into the folder containing the executable

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: No, I am not so stupid... all the dll's are in the same folder...

Comment: This is a repo on github: [link]https://github.com/Intrigger/WebcamDuo

Comment: My problem is that it works fine on my pc, but at another PC it crashes when I use methods from OpenCV

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, finally. The problem was in OpenCV version. I used to have .dll of OpenCV 4.5.5 but now I tried to use OpenCV 3.8 ... or smth like that and it works fine!))